# Flatten a Dictionary<int, List<object>>

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, key-value

I have a dictionary which has an integer Key that represents a year, and a Value which is a list of object `Channel`. I need to flatten the data and create a new object from it.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
Dictionary<int, List<Channel>> myDictionary;

foreach(var x in myDictionary)
{
    var result = (from a in x.Value
                  from b in anotherList
                  where a.ChannelId == b.ChannelId
                  select new NewObject
                  {
                      NewObjectYear = x.Key,
                      NewObjectName = a.First().ChannelName,
                  }).ToList();
    list.AddRange(result);
}
```

Notice that I am using the `Key` to be the value of property `NewObjectYear`.
I want to get rid of foreach since the dictionary contains a lot of data and doing some joins inside the iteration makes it very slow. So I decided to refactor and came up with this:

```
var flatten = myDictionary.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Select(y => 
                  new KeyValuePair<int, Channel>(x.Key, y))).ToList();
```

But with this, I couldn't get the `Key` directly. Using something like `flatten.Select(x => x.Key)` is definitely not the correct way. So I tried finding other ways to flatten that would be favorable for my scenario but failed. I also thought about creating a class which will contain the year and the list from the flattened but I don't know how. 
Please help me with this.

Also, is there also another way that doesn't have the need to create a new class?

Comment: Why do you mean you 'couldn't get the key' directly - what you've done looks fine.

Comment: "...is definitely not the correct way" what *is* a correct way then ?

Comment: I don't understand. In `from a in x.Value`, `a` is a `Channel`, not a `List<Channel>`. Indeed you have `a.ChannelId`, but how then can you use `a.First()` later on?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you are trying to do only filtering, you do not need join for that:

```
var anotherListIDs = new HashSet<int>(anotherList.Select(c => c.ChannelId));            

foreach (var x in myDictionary)
{
    list.AddRange(x.Value
        .Where(c => anotherListIDs.Contains(c.ChannelId))
        .Select(c => new NewObject
        {
            NewObjectYear = x.Key,
            NewObjectName = c.First().ChannelName,
        }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do realise, that if the second element of the list in a specific dictionary element has a matching channelId, that you return the first element of this list, don't you?

```
var otherList = new OtherItem[]
{
    new OtherItem() {ChannelId = 1, ...}
}
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<Channel>[]
{
    { 10,                             // Key
      new List<Channel>()             // Value
      {
          new Channel() {ChannelId = 100, Name = "100"},
          new Channel() {ChannelId = 1, Name = "1"},
      },
};
```

Although the 2nd element has a matching ChannelId, you return the Name of the first element.

Anyway, let's assume this is what you really want. You are right, your function isn't very efficient.

Your dictionary implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, List<Channel>>`. Therefore every `x` in your `foreach` is a `KeyValuePair<int, List<Channel>`. Every `x.Value` is a `List<Channel>`.

So for every element in your dictionary (which is a `KeyValuePair<int, List<Channel>`), you take the complete list, and perform a full inner join of the complete list with `otherList`, and for the result you take the key of the `KeyValuePair` and the first element of the List in the `KeyValuePair`.

And even though you might not use the complete result, but only the first or the first few, because of `FirstOrDefault()`, or `Take(3)`, you do this for every element of every list in your Dictionary.

Indeed your query could be much more efficient.

As you use the `ChannelIds` in your `OtherList` only to find out if it is present, one of the major improvements would be to convert the `ChannelIds` of `OtherList` to a `HashSet<int>` where you have superior fast lookup to check if the ChannelId of one of the values in your Dictionary is in the `HashSet`.

So for every element in your dictionary, you only have to check every `ChannelId` in the list to see if one of them is in the `HashSet`. As soon as you've found one, you can stop and return only the first element of the List and the Key.

My solution is an extension function of Dictionary>. See [Extension Methods Demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
public static IEnumerable<NewObject> ExtractNewObjects(this Dictionary<int, List<Channel>> dictionary,
     IEnumerable<OtherItem> otherList)
{
    // I'll only use the ChannelIds of the otherList, so extract them
    IEnumerable<int> otherChannelIds = otherList
        .Select(otherItem => otherItem.ChannelId);
    return dictionary.ExtractNewObjects(otherChannelIds);
}
```

This calls the other ExtractNewobjects:

```
public static IEnumerable<NewObject> ExtractNewObjects(this Dictionary<int, List<Channel>> dictionary,
     IEnumerable<int> otherChannelIds)
{
    var channelIdsSet = new  HashSet<int>(otherChannelIds));
    // duplicate channelIds will be removed automatically

    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<Channel>> keyValuePair in dictionary)
    {
        // is any ChannelId in the list also in otherChannelIdsSet?
        // every keyValuePair.Value is a List<Channel>
        // every Channel has a ChannelId
        // channelId found if any of these ChannelIds in in the HashSet
        bool channelIdFound = keyValuePair.Value
           .Any(channel => otherChannelIdsSet.Contains(channel.ChannelId);
        if (channelIdFound)
        {
            yield return new NewObject()
            {
                NewObjectYear = keyValuePair.Key,
                NewObjectName = keyValuePair.Value
                                .Select(channel => channel.ChannelName)
                                .FirstOrDefault(),
            };
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
IEnumerable<OtherItem> otherList = ...
Dictionary<int, List<Channel>> dictionary = ...

IEnumerable<Newobject> extractedNewObjects = dictionary.ExtractNewObjects(otherList);

var someNewObjects = extractedNewObjects
    .Take(5)      // here we see the benefit from the yield return
    .ToList();
```

We can see four efficiency improvements:

- the use of `HashSet<int>` enables a very fast lookup to see if the `ChannelId` is in `OtherList`
- the use of `Any()` stops enumerating the `List<Channel>` as soon as we've found a matching `Channelid` in the `HashSet`
- the use of `yield return` makes that you don't enumerate over more elements in your Dictionary than you'll actually use.
- The use of `Select` and `FirstOrDefault` when creating `NewObjectName` prevents exceptions if `List<Channel>` is empty

Comment: OPs question contains `a.First().ChannelName`, where `a` is a Channel. Channel therefore implements `IEnumerable<something>`, it is not `IEnumerable<Channel>` as you treat it. From now on it is all doomed I am afraid.